# PHP Contact form

Tags: php, forms

I have an issue with a PHP contact form I am trying to create for WordPress. I have an error on the `$headers` line that says `syntax error, unexpected ''` but I'm not sure why as it looks correct to me. I also think that `function my_form_message(){` is not closed properly. Any help would be great. Thanks

```
// Form markup
 function html_form_code() { ?>

 <form action="<?php esc_url( $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] ); ?>" method="post">
   <p>Your Name (required)<br />
     <input type="text" name="cf-name" pattern="[a-zA-Z0-9 ]+" value="<?php isset( $_POST["cf-name"] ) ? esc_attr( $_POST["cf-name"] ) : ''; ?>" size="40" />
   </p>
   <p>Your Email (required)<br />
     <input type="email" name="cf-email" value="<?php isset( $_POST["cf-email"] ) ? esc_attr( $_POST["cf-email"] ) : ''; ?>" size="40" />
   </p>
   <p>Your Message (required)<br />
     <textarea rows="10" cols="35" name="cf-message"><?php isset( $_POST["cf-message"] ) ? esc_attr( $_POST["cf-message"] ) : ''; ?></textarea>
   </p>
   <p><input type="submit" name="cf-submitted" value="Send"/></p>
 </form>

 <?php }

// Form validation
 function my_validate_form() {

  $errors = new WP_Error();

  if ( isset( $_POST[ 'content' ] ) && $_POST[ 'content' ] !== '' ) {
    $errors->add( 'cheater', 'Sorry, this field should not be filled. Are you trying to cheat?' );
  }

  if ( isset( $_POST[ 'cf-name' ] ) && $_POST[ 'cf-name' ] == '' ) {
    $errors->add('name_error', 'Please fill in a valid name.' );
  }

  if ( isset( $_POST[ 'cf-email' ] ) && $_POST[ 'cf-email' ] == '' ) {
    $errors->add('email_error', 'Please fill in a valid email.' );
  }

  if ( isset( $_POST[ 'cf-message' ] ) && $_POST[ 'cf-message' ] == '' ) {
    $errors->add('message_error', 'Please fill in a valid message.' );
  }

  return $errors;
}

// Form delivery
 function deliver_mail( $args = array() ) {

  // This $default array is a way to initialize some default values that will be overwritten by our $args array.
  // We could add more keys as we see fit and it's a nice way to see what parameter we are using in our function.
  // It will only be overwritten with the values of our $args array if the keys are present in $args.
  // This uses WP wp_parse_args() function.
  $defaults = array(
    'name'    => '',
    'email'   => '',
    'message' => '',
    'to'      => get_option( 'admin_email' ), // get the administrator's email address
  );

  $args = wp_parse_args( $args, $defaults );

  $headers = "From: $args['name'] <$args['email']>" . "\r\n";

  // Send email returns true on success, false otherwise
  if( wp_mail( $args['to'], $args['message'], $headers ) ) {
    return;
  }
  else {
    return false;
  }
}

// Form sanitize
function my_sanitize_field( $input ){

  return trim( stripslashes( sanitize_text_field ( $input ) ) );

}

// Form succsess message
function my_form_message(){

  global $errors;
  if( is_wp_errors( $errors ) && empty( $errors->errors ) ){

    echo '<div class="cf-success">';
    echo '<p>Thank you for contacting us '. $_POST['cf-name'] .', a member of our team will be in touch with you shortly.</p>';
    echo '</div>';

    //Empty $_POST because we already sent email
    $_POST = '';

  }
  else {

  if( is_wp_errors( $errors ) && ! empty( $errors->errors ) ){

    $error_messages = $errors->get_error_messages();
    foreach( $error_messages as $k => $message ){
        echo '<div class="cf-error ' . $k . '">';
        echo '<p>' . $message . '</p>';
        echo '</div>';

    }

  }

}

// Form shortcode
add_shortcode( 'contact_form', 'cf_contact_form' );
function cf_contact_form() {

  ob_start();

  my_form_message();
  html_form_code();

  return ob_get_clean();
}

// Error validation
add_action( 'init', 'my_cf_form');
function my_cf_form(){

  if( isset( $_POST['cf-submitted'] ) ) {

    global $errors;
    $errors = my_validate_form();
    if( empty( $errors->errors ) ){

       $args = array(
         'name'    => my_sanitize_field( $_POST['cf-name'] ),
         'email'   => my_sanitize_field( $_POST['cf-email'] ),
         'message' => my_sanitize_field( $_POST['cf-message'] ),
       );
       deliver_mail( $args );
    }
    else {
      return $errors;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Whats with the down vote?

Comment: Why not use a plugin as Contact Form 7?

Comment: For a number of reasons really. A) I want to learn and understand the code. B) I don't like ramming my sites full of plugins, when things can be built from scratch. C) I think certain plugins introduce more security risks to sites so it's best to keep plugin use to a minimum. D) Plugins create extra server requests, their code isn't always optimised as often they are designed to cater for a range of needs and as a result can slow the site down. So I would rather streamline my sites as much as possible.

Comment: A) Good way to learn the code :) 
B) Understandable, plugins can be cluttered and needs to be updated - often is over-engineered to a simple purpose. 
C) I agree, keep it to a minimum. 
D) True, in most cases.

Point taken :)

Comment: Hopefully the above code will help someone else in the future too. So win win. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To access array values within a double quoted string use the form:

```
 $headers = "From: {$args['name']}  <{$args['email']}>" . "\r\n";
```

You are right: your function needs one more `}` to close it correctly.

Comment: Do you mean like this? $headers = "From: {$args['name'] <$args['email']>}" . "\r\n";

Comment: @user53340 no. Braces around each variable.

Comment: I've edited the question to show the full line. Typing code on a phone isn't the easiest :-)

Comment: I get the same error unless I remove the <> from around the email variable. Will it still work okay?

Comment: ahh that makes sense! Thanks for that. Okay so now I have a fatal error Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function is_wp_errors() PHP isn't my strong point at all. Do you know what this could be referring to? Thanks again

Comment: Exactly what the error says. There is no is_wp_errors(). Try is_wp_error()

Comment: sweet that's fixed it. Thanks! How did you know to use is_wp_error() instead of is_wp_errors() ? Thanks again

Comment: I've used it before, but to remind myself I googled and the correct function showed up along with lots of helpful pages about using the WP_error object.

Comment: I guess it's a case of knowing what to look for. Someone else on stack exchange wrote this in answer to another question I asked about creating a simple php form with validation. So I'm not entirely sure what every bit does. Thank you for your help though.